# Diff between meteor method and meteor pub/sub

Tags: meteor

I working with meteor to create an app. In meteor **Meteor.methods** and **Meteor.publish** are used to perform database operation.`I know use of Meteor methods and pub/sub`

My question is there any criteria when to use  **Meteor.methods** and when **Meteor.publish**?.

Comment: why this question is down voted ?

Comment: Agreed, Upvoted you back :), as i found this useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Meteor.publish` is the *pub* part of *pub-sub* obviously. As data gets added or changed that is being published the server will automatically send it over to any client that has subscribed to that publication.

`Meteor.call` is *request-response*. You make a request, you get a response. Party's over. If data changes on the server that the method uses your client won't know about it until you make another call.

Comment: Just a follow up question: so does `Meteor.call` affects `Meteor.publish` implicitly when something changes on the collection with `Meteor.call`? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - if `Meteor.call()` causes documents in a published collection to be inserted, deleted, or updated then the publication will update automatically. In fact it doesn't matter how the collection is changed, publish will pick up the change. Meteor does this basically by tailing mongodb's oplog.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor Publish Subscribe is a way to allow access (read and write) to clients, and to keep all clients and server updated with the latest data.
Meteor Publish/Subscribe has only to do with meteor database.

Meteor methods is much more, it can be used for various uses, such as making calls to API's (HTTP calls to your REST API's), etc. (P.S. It is recommended to make these calls from server side for security reasons).

Also, when fetching data by calling Meteor Method (using Meteor.call), you can do some kind of verification or validation on server side before fetching or returning the data.

And yes, Michel Floyd's answer is another great point.